# Intellisense Javascript static namespacing

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to get intellisense in visual studio code. The following code works fine:

```
var Bar = function(){
}

Bar.prototype.logMsg = function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
}
```

[Intellisense working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGVAk.png)

But I don't recive any intellisense when writing:

```
var FOO = {};

FOO.Bar = function(){
}

FOO.Bar.prototype.logMsg = function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
}
```

[Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr5hb.png)

This might be due to restrictions I'm not aware of, but I can't find any documentation/posts mentioning this. Is there a way to get it working without rewriting big parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on TypeScript and JavaScript support in VSCode. As of VSCode 1.8.1, this type of dynamic property assignment is not something that our IntelliSense recognizes.

We use [TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript) to power both our TypeScript and JavaScript IntelliSense, and while TypeScript is able to recognize the common `prototype` pattern shown in your first example, it does not recognize properties added to an object, as in your second example. This means that `FOO.Bar` will always have an `any` type.

We're tracking support for this type of IntelliSense in the TypeScript project: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13271